# How do I open / edit a .sdb file

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a .sdb database file which I need to open. It's the database behind Song Pro (http://creationsoftware.com/).

Google seems to think that openoffice may be able to open this, as it might come from star office. But I can't persuade the file to open in Base 3.2 and there are no reliable instructions as most google results are of the extension definition type.

Initially I could do with doing this in a database browser to see how the database is laid out. But assuming it is holding the correct data I will then want to do this programmatically.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
Jona

Comment: Depending on the age of the software it's probably: a text file, an SQLite database, or a [dBase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase) file with a 'custom' file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](http://openlp.org/forums/general-stuff/general-discussion/songpro-migration) says that the SongPro .sdb file is an MSAccess database and you can just rename it to .mdb and open it with MS Access.  There's also a script linked that someone has written to convert the contents of the database.

Comment: Thanks for this, naturally I discovered this about 2 mins after posting the question, assume that .sdb stands for Songpro Database. If you open the file in Hex view you can see the "Standard Jet DB" header.